# navigating to next panel Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working in a Angular project,I have many panels ,in each panel I have some input fields and ends with a continue button.

**problem:** The user, who is logging to the site needs to click so many continue button to complete filling all the panels.

**requirement:** once all the input field are entered it should automatically navigate to the next panel without the user clicking on the continue button.

**solution:** trigger when the (form is valid  && onblur of the last input field in the panel)

But I am not so convinced with this approach,Is there any better way of doing it.so kindly provide with some suggestion.

note: continue button will stay in the panel to use when user return backs to the previous panel if needed.

Comment: What have you done so far?Provide a Plunkr

Comment: @satej : now once all the inputs are entered, user should click on the continue button to move to the next panel

Comment: now the form validity is checked on the continue button

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router